# Register PostBackTriggers in a GridView nested within an UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, gridview

UpdatePanel code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="MyUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID = "MyPlaceHolder" runat = "server">
        <asp:GridView runat = "server" ID = "MyGridView" DataKeyNames = "ID, Name" AutoGenerateColumns = "false" ShowHeader = "true" GridLines = "None" OnRowDeleting = "Delete" OnRowEditing = "Rename">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID = "ExportButton" Width="15" Height="15" rel="tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Export" runat = "server" OnClick = "Export"/>            
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID = "otherBtnID" />
</Triggers>
```

It works fine when I remove `UpdatePanel`. But with `UpdatePanel`, I cannot be able to register my `ExportButton ID` in `PostBackTrigger`.

It throws an error:

```
A control with ID 'ExportButton' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'MyUpdatePanel
```

What is the proper way to register `ExportButton`?

I have tried to register from code behind, but not succeeded.
`OnExportClick` code:

```
ImageButton imgDownload = (ImageButton)sender;
AsyncPostBackTrigger trigger = new AsyncPostBackTrigger();
trigger.ControlID = imgDownload.UniqueID;
trigger.EventName = "Click";
MyUpdatePanel.Triggers.Add(trigger);
```

Comment: the markup you've posted is not relevant, you are referencing `otherBtnID` at the trigger

Comment: Try adding "AutoPostback" on the image button.

Comment: @nikis: Thank u for ur comment. Its an other Button which is out of this UpdatePanel. I have tried <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="ExportButton" /> , but it didn't work.

Comment: @Alok: Thank u for ur comment.I didn't found "AutoPostBack" Property in ImageButton